# "would" as an auxiliary for present tense conditionals

Tags: conditionals, present-tense, be, would

Both of these sentences feel wrong to me:

`if I am alone, I will go today`

`if I would be alone, I will go today`

By looking up some [rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403146/would-present-tense-in-conditional-clauses), it seems that using `would` in the protasis is a common mistake, even if there are a few [exceptions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34299/if-i-would-go-there-i-would-be-in-trouble-correct/34304#34304) of the form `if I would [verb], then I would [verb]` (but given that the protasis is "more in the past" than the main clause, shouldn't it be `if I would [verb], then I will [verb]`?).

On the other hand, the common example of conditionals with the verb "to be" are things like "if I am lucky...", "if I am able...", "if god is...". In all of those cases it makes sense to be uncertain: we don't know yet if we are lucky in a certain circumstance, for example.

But it wouldn't make sense to write "if I am alone" right now: I should know already! Either I am alone or I'm not... In which case I should just drop the conditional.

Context: a friend that is learning English wrote

`if I be alone, I will go today`

I suggested:

```
"If I would be alone, I will go today" (if there's a chance that you might still go, if your friend might not be with you for the whole day)
"If I were alone, I would've gone today" (for an unreal past situation: you know that you were not alone, and the decision has already been taken)
```

I can sidestep the issue with something like `If I end up being alone, I will go today`, but I'm concerned that my previous suggestion to them might've been ungrammatical.

Comment: Are you using American English? AmE has uses of *would* which are not valid in British English.

Comment: Neither me nor my friend are British nor American, but I think that British English would be slightly more appropriate. If you have links that explain the different usage of *would* in American English I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: If you're not American, don't use *would* in the protasis. (And even if you want to learn to speak American English, I don't believe this is viewed as acceptable in all regions of the U.S. yet; don't do it. And especially don't do it the way you're suggesting; this is wrong even for those people who do use *would* in if clauses.)

Comment: "If I would" is unschooled in AmE speech. And I'd bet the British counterparts of AmE speakers would say it also.

Comment: @Lambie: there are parts of the U.S. where *if I would* is common enough that I believe it's not viewed as unschooled. Educated people from those parts who have gone to college still use it.

Comment: @PeterShor It's unschooled if the academy says it is (for written text). I am  not referring to spoken English. This issue is not just about American English. That is a untrue statement.  It is not acceptable in written papers and essays. And ngrams cannot prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use my own analysis of English conditionals. I don't have any good references for this.

In English, conditionals either come in irrealis or in realis moods.
Both the protasis and the main clause should be in the same mood.

There is a non-standard set of tenses widely used in the U.S. in the protasis for the *irrealis*. There is really no reason for you to use this; even in some parts of the U.S., it's viewed as a sign of lack of education. In other parts, it's in widespread use, but I believe the standard grammar is also.

In standard English, the choices for the conditional are:

REALIS:

```
        _______________________________________
        |   Protasis     |   Main Clause      |
        ---------------------------------------
   Past | If I went       | I saw             |
Present | If I go         | I see             |
 Future | If I go         | I will see        |
        ---------------------------------------
```

IRREALIS:

```
        _______________________________________
        |   Protasis      |   Main Clause     |
        ---------------------------------------
   Past | If I had gone   | I would have seen |
Present | If I went       | I would see       |
 Future | If I were to go | I would see       |
        ---------------------------------------
```

NON-STANDARD AmE IRREALIS:

```
        ____________________________________________
        |   Protasis           |   Main Clause     |
        -------------------------------------------|
   Past | If I would have gone | I would have seen |
Present | If I would go        | I would see       |
 Future | If I were to go      | I would see       |
        --------------------------------------------
```

There are some caveats to this classification, such as that there is a very fuzzy relation between the actual time frame and what I'm calling the "future" and the "present", and that we only use what I call the present realis for habitual conditions or eternal truths (*If I take the subway to work, I don't have to pay for parking,* or *if you drop something, it falls*).

Your sentence

> If I would be alone, I will go today,

combines *irrealis* and *realis*, and so is incorrect.

And your sentence

> If I were alone, I would've gone today.

combines the present irrealis in the protasis with the past irrealis in the main clause. This is a *mixed conditional*, meaning the *alone* part is in the present, but the *would have gone* is in the past. It's grammatical in some situations. For example, you're traveling with your family, and you want to say that if they were not along, you would have made the choice to go today. But probably what you want to say is one of:

> If I were alone, I would go today.
>   If I had been alone, I would have gone today.

Comment: I say this: If you accept: If I would go and If I would have gone, you  then have to accept an entire list of dialectal features along with it.  I really would like to know how this myth got started. It reminds me of French people telling me when I taught English in France that "British English is better than American English". Both have class-based and class-bound dialects.There is nothing wrong with that. People speak like/as they speak. But it shouldn't be hoisted up the flagpole so it flaps in the breeze.

Comment: @Lambie: what myth?

Comment: Do I have to repeat it?  The non-standard AmE  irrealis myth. Do you seriously think every working class stiff (as one way to put it) in Canada, Ireland, the British Isles, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa (English-speaking SA) don't have the same non-standard  irrealis? When one uses standard forms, one is either born into them or acquires them through education or a concerted effort.

Comment: Well ... *something* has been going on with *if I would have* in the U.S. since 1980. [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+would+have%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cif+I+would+have%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20would%20have%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20would%20have%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). But maybe it's just that it's working its way out of the working classes into the class of people who actually write stuff that finds its way into books.

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you that the very same issue is discussed in Spanish all the time with regard to expressing irrealis utterances? https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=41262   The people who write books (not referring to novels) are just unschooled (as are many a media pundit). Obviously, the standard form takes a concerted effort (by parents, educators, grammar lovers) to impart it  to young 'uns and not using it impoverishes the logical landscape for expressing many ideas. Apart from that Avanti i populo and "let the people speak."

Comment: You wrote: "Both the protasis and the main clause should be in the same mood." -- by "main clause" do you mean that the *then*-clause in a conditional sentence is an independent clause? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Mr Reality: I am using the terminology given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#English_language_teaching). I don't necessarily *mean* anything by it.

Comment: Wikipedia does [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause) "independent clause" by "main clause". I was confused whether conditional sentences have independent clauses or not, that's why I asked. I searched a bit more now, but didn't find a definitive analysis of conditional sentences.